# WSASetSocketSecurity missing

Tags: c++

Visual Studio 2015 tells me it can not find `WSASetSocketSecurity`.
The dll exists and also includes seem to be fine.

My includes:

```
windows.h
stdio.h
Wincrypt.h
Ws2tcpip.h
mstcpip.h
iostream
winsock2.h
rpc.h
ntdsapi.h
tchar.h
pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
pragma comment(lib,"fwpuclnt.lib")
pragma comment(lib,"ntdsapi.lib")
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3 headers below need to be included in this specific order :

- `winsock2.h`
- `mstcpip.h`
- `Ws2tcpip.h`

Technically this is because of the macro/define mechanism in winsock ; `winsock2.h` enables winsock, `mstcpip.h` enables secure socket extension, and `Ws2tcpip.h` defines the functions.

I'm not sure if there is a particular reason to make this work like that, but that's how it is.

Comment: it is just that, thanks. But why? I do not understand the reason of this order

Comment: @TonyFotter It's as I wrote (because of macros). Basically, `Ws2tcpip.h` defines the secure socket functions only if a specific macro was defined in `mstcpip.h`, and `mstcpip.h` defines this macro only if winsock is enabled by a define in `winsock2.h`.

Comment: @ElderBug I get the same error even tough the order of #includes is correct (WSASetSocketSecurity was not declared)

Comment: @J.Doe I can't tell with no details. Do you have any `#define` before the includes ? Maybe a WINVER ? This needs vista, so WINVER 0x600 at least.

Comment: In addition, you may also want to insert `#include <ws2ipdef.h>` before `#include <mstcpip.h>`. Some of the macros and inline functions in mstcpip.h may not compile without ws2ipdef.h.

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestion doesn't work, try defining your `_WIN32_WINNT` macro like:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x06030000  
#endif
```

You'll find in a header file like `Ws2tcpip.h` that the function `WSASetSocketSecurity` and others can only be accessed if the `_WIN32_WINNT` is above a certain version.

Put the above macro before your your `winsock2.h` or related headers.